Ubuntu persistently boots into error with blinking character. Ctrl+Alt+F(1-6) works only sometimes
About a week ago I installed a new SSD Ubuntu 22.04. While also dual booting it with another SSD containing Windows 11.
Shortly after I began having issues at boot with an error and blinking character.

I was told to disable the fast boot of Windows 11 and to access the terminal or GUI through Ctrl+Alt+f1-f6. The terminal worked sometimes and sometimes it just was stuck.
Later on, I found a post saying to replace the boot parameter in the grub file "quiet splash" with "text" to make the error more descriptive which ironically acted as a bandaid preventing error.
I did try setting it to text splash or even back to quiet splash, but it usually resulted in the same error with Plymouth 120s.


I was told that it was a normal error, but there was also a BIOS error while powering off.

Hardware specs:
   Type: notebook
   Name: Lenovo Legion Pro 5 16IRX8
   CPU: Intel Core i9 13900HX Raptor Lake
   Memory: 32GB DDR5
   GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 8GB
   Storage: 2✕SSD 1000GB

I wanted to just add that it's not always that I had this error with quiet splash. It's hit and miss but it leans on error more.

Is it perhaps problem with nvidia driver? just my assumption because text boot mode works.

69% unanswered...
